# How can I find Average accurately in my query

Tags: postgresql

I want average but its showing null. I want the average of score present in different ids

```
  select avg(score*100)from daily_stats1 where id=10 and id=11
```

Comment: `where id=10 and id=11` will never return any rows as a column can't have the value 10 **and** the value 11 at the same time. You probably meant `where id = 10 or id = 11`

Comment: Thank you,it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of `null` values using `coalesce` function:

```
select avg(coalesce(score, 0)*100)from daily_stats1 where id=10 and id=11
```

Comment: I got the same result as null

Comment: as @a_horse_with_no_name stated in comment your where clause is invalid, there should be `or` if you want to select two values